# A question about non-linear least square method...

Tags: matrices

I am trying to fit a set of points into a sine function, using nonlinear least square method. The final step to obtain the derivative of its parameters is given by
the equation (8) of:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonlinearLeastSquaresFitting.html

$$\mathbf A^Td\beta=(\mathbf A^T\mathbf A)d\lambda$$

My question is when I use the above equation to solve for $d\lambda$, can I just put the inverse of $(\mathbf A^T\mathbf A)$ to the left hand side?

$$(\mathbf A^T\mathbf A)^{-1}\mathbf A^Td\beta=d\lambda$$

I call MATLAB function inv() but it warned me the matrix is nearly singular under current precision. Seems like the only solution is to use pseudo inverse pinv(), and the fitting result is not too bad. But is that correct, did I mess something up about least square method?

Answer (score 0):

The issue on $A^T A$ being (nearly) non-singular is likely due co-linearity.    This will likely lead to unreliable coefficient estimates do the large condition number of $A^T A.$   The function  **pinv** generates the Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse,  in which you obtain a minimal residual solution for $\| B x  - y\|$, where in your case $B=A^T A,$ $x=d\lambda$ and $y=A^T \beta.$

Also,  note that $dlamba = (A'*A)\backslash ((A')*dBeta)$ is better code if $A^T A$ well conditioned.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should go for another way fitting into sine wave because I tried the least square procedure but the norm of the residual does not converge, and the performance rely heavily on whether I choose a full period or a half period of the data set.